# Swift - Core location request permission if not granted

Tags: swift, permissions, core-location

Is there any way to ask users to give permission for location detection, if they denied when they were first asked?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For getting user's current location you need to declare:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

In viewDidLoad():

```
  // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
  self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() 

  // For use in foreground
  self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

  if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
      locationManager.delegate = self
      locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
  }
```

Then in CLLocationManagerDelegate method you can get user's current location coordinates:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
}
```

If user has denied the location then give him option to change location permission from settings:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("error::: \(error)")
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Settings", message: "Allow location from settings", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: TextMessages().callAlertTitle, style: .Default, handler: { action in
        switch action.style{
        case .Default: UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
        case .Cancel: print("cancel")
        case .Destructive: print("destructive")
        }
    }))
}
```

**NOTE:**

Make sure to add the Privacy key (NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription) to Info.plist file.

Comment: and make sure to add the Privacy key (NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription) to plist file.

Comment: @LahiruPinto Yes, Thanks.

Comment: you can check current status is denied by `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied`

Answer (score 3):

No, you can just remind them inside app within an alert, like "For better usage, we will suggest you to give us the permissions to use your location". And to add button "Go to settings" that will redirect the user to the Location Permissions for your application.

Comment: is this seriously the answer ?

Comment: @NumanKaraaslan Yep. And if you will read it carefully, you will find that this is a short variant of the accepted answer.